# modulus of $ x^2+iy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=x^2+iy^2 $ I what to find the modulo of $f(z)$, $|x^2+iy^2|$

My try:$|f(z)|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}= \sqrt{x^4+y^4}$ but the answer should be $\color{blue}1$ and I do not anderstand why

The original question is to prove that $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}(x^2+iy^2)dz\bigg|\leq2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Gamma=\{{z_0=-i } \text{ to the point} z_1=i\}$

Here is the answer, but how in the last line the modulo of f(z) is 1?

[image]

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers then you're right .

Comment: I edited the qustion, mybe it is because that it is from $z_0$ to $z_1$?

Comment: You probably mean the modulus ?

Comment: How is $z$ related to $x$ and $y$? $z=x+iy$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe, English is not my first language

Comment: Hem, $|f(z)|\le1$, not $=1$, and under an integral !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't known what $\Gamma$ is, except that it runs from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$, both compatible with $|f(z)|=1$.

If you need to enforce this condition for all intermediate points, you can just set

$$x^4+y^4=1,$$ i.e.

$$y=\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}.$$

---

**Update**:

After seeing the true question,

$$|x^2+iy^2|=|0^2+iy^2|=y^2\le1.$$